# AWS boto3: Simulating IAM role for a given permission json policy file

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to use the AWS [IAM-Simulator with boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_custom_policy)

Lets say I have files *policy1.json, policy2.json* which are valid aws IAM policies jsons. Lets say json1 holds :

```
{
"Version": "2023-12-15",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/my_cool_tag": "*"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I want to check if a user with an applied role with lets say `role_arn = 12345`
can perform the actions specified in the policy json files.

I want it to be generic, that is to be able to receive any valid policy file and simulate wether the attached *arn role* could perform all the actions with/without conditions specified in the policy.json file (for any file)

Is there a way to use boto3 to achieve this? I tried reading the documentation but couldn't find any example that does this

For this example, I came up with:

```
        ressult1 =iam_client.simulate_principal_policy(
        PolicySourceArn=12345,
        ActionNames=[
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "ec2:CreateTags"
    ])

    ressult2 =iam_client.simulate_principal_policy(
        PolicySourceArn=12345,
        ActionNames=[ec2:DeleteSnapshot],
        ContextEntries=[
            {"ContextKeyName": "ec2:ResourceTag/my_cool_tag", "ContextKeyValues": [""], "ContextKeyType": "string",}
        ])
```

But this isn't generic
 would like to do something like this:

```
    with open('policy1.json') as json_file:
          policy_data = json.load(json_file)
          ressult =iam_client.simulate_principal_policy(
                     PolicySourceArn=12345,
                     policy_dict = policy_loaded)
```

would appreciate some help here.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you would like the policy simulator to extract the actions from the supplied policy? I don't think that's how it works. When calling `simulate_principal_policy()`, you need to provide **who** (ARN) and **what** (action), plus any parameters, to determine whether it would successfully run.

Comment: Yes this is what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no API call to do that.